# Using JSON variable in setInterval time

Tags: javascript, html, json, setinterval

I have script that currently takes a json object and converts it to an array by pageID which contains an array for 'content'.

This works fine and I'm calling it on page load then calling it within setInterval. This also works, but I modified it to use the 'duration' value of the current page element and it;s not dynamic but it actually seems like it just uses the duration value of the last element (which would make sense for an array, I guess)

How can I change this so that the current setInterval timer is always the current elements 'Duration' value?

You can run the snippet below to see the current function

```js
const obj = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "10",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "10",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "94",
    "page_type_id": "1",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "15",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "1",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nFull Page<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
];

let counter = 0;

var fullContent = document.getElementById('fullContent');
var leftContent = document.getElementById('leftContent');
var rightContent = document.getElementById('rightContent');

var fullColumn = document.getElementById('fullColumn');
var leftColumn = document.getElementById('leftColumn');
var rightColumn = document.getElementById('rightColumn');


const pages_array = obj.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, obj) {
  const current_pageID = item.pageID;
  const current_pageType = item.page_type_id;
  const duration = item.duration;
  const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);

  if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
    const new_Page = {
      pageID: current_pageID,
      pageType: current_pageType,
      duration: duration,
      content: [item]
    }
    pages_array.push(new_Page);
  } else {
    exisiting_page.content.push(item)
  }

  return pages_array;
}, []);

/*Call reloadFunction immediately so there's no initial delay*/
reloadFunction();

/*then call it withing setInterval to use the 'duration' value in json and convert to milliseconds*/
//setInterval(reloadFunction, parseInt(pages_array[counter].duration) * 1000);

function reloadFunction() {
  const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter];

  fullContent.innerHTML = '';
  rightContent.innerHTML = '';
  leftContent.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++) {
    

    if (parseInt(pages_array[counter].pageType) == 1) {
      console.log("Paren pageType => ", pages_array[counter].pageType);

      fullContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 1 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : fullContent.innerHTML;


      fullColumn.style.display = "block";


      leftColumn.style.display = "none";
      rightColumn.style.display = "none";

    }
    if (parseInt(pages_array[counter].pageType) == 2) {
      console.log("Paren pageType => ", pages_array[counter].pageType);

      leftContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 2 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : leftContent.innerHTML;
      rightContent.innerHTML = currentJSONobject.content[i].panel_type_id == 3 ? currentJSONobject.content[i].content : rightContent.innerHTML;

      leftColumn.style.display = "block";
      rightColumn.style.display = "block";

      fullColumn.style.display = "none";

    }
  }

  console.log(pages_array[counter]);
  console.log(setInterval);

setTimeout(reloadFunction, parseInt(pages_array[counter].duration) * 1000);

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === pages_array.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }

}
console.log(obj);
console.log(pages_array);
```

```html
<div class="row middle" id="middle" style="background-image: url();">
  <!-- Full Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-12" id="fullColumn">
    <div class="fullContent" id="fullContent" style="height: 100%; ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Full Page Divs -->

  <!-- Half Page Divs -->
  <div class="col-lg-6 leftColumn " id="leftColumn" style="align-items: center;">

    <div class="leftContent" id="leftContent" style=" margin:auto; height: 100%; ">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-6 rightColumn" id="rightColumn">

    <div class="rightContent" id="rightContent" style=" height: 100%; ">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can’t change the timeout of a setInterval once it’s invoked.  Use repeated calls to setTimeout instead.

Comment: How would I convert this to keep the functionality but using setTimeout though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the setInterval timeout can’t be changed use successive calls to setTimeout.

```
/*Call reloadFunction immediately so there's no initial delay*/
// keep this
reloadFunction();

/*then call it withing setInterval to use the 'duration' value in json and convert to milliseconds*/
// get rid of this
//setInterval(reloadFunction, parseInt(pages_array[counter].duration) * 1000);

function reloadFunction() {
  // most of your code

  setTimeout(reloadFunction, parseInt(pages_array[counter].duration) * 1000);

  counter += 1;
  if (counter === pages_array.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot now, thank you! For some reason I thought setInterval could be dynamic

Comment: Sorry, can you actually check my updated snippet? I've implemented this but it doesn't seem to work at all. Or should the setTimeout be outside of the for loop?

Comment: The call to setTimeout needs to be right before counter += 1